# It is not possible to introduce multiplication in $v_n$(For $n>2$) so as to satisfy all field properties

Tags: vector-spaces, motivation

In the book Calculus Vol 1- Tom M. Apostol .Before beginning to define the dot product of two vectors he tells

> It can be shown that except $n=1, 2$, it is not possible to introduce multiplication in
>   $V_n$ so as to satisfy all the field properties.

Which I think might be a motivation to defining dot product and cross product(for $n=3$).

I know that

For $n=1$ we can simply define multiplication as $\left(a_1\right)\times\left(a_2\right)=\left(a_1a_2\right)$

And for $n=2$ $\left(a_1,b_1\right)\times\left(a_2,b_2\right)=\left(a_1a_2-b_1b_2,a_1b_2+a_2b_1\right)$

I can't really follow why similar definition to $n>3$ creates problems

Can anyone explain the proof?. If there are better ways that served as motivation please explain/share link.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that for $n = 2$, the multiplication comes from the multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$. For $\varphi : V_2 \to \mathbb{C}$, $\varphi((a, b)) = a+bi$, then $(a_1, a_2)\times(b_1, b_2) = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi((a_1, a_2))\times\varphi((b_1, b_2)))$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: @Michael Albanese . I wanted to know about the problem in the box.

Comment: Actually, I see little *motivation* for introducing dot product and cross product from the fact that we cannot have a field. After all, we can have a skew field in dimension four and a division algebra in dimension eight ... The dot product and cross product certainly have motivations that come from their *utility* instead of the absence of a field structure. Especially, the introduction of dot/cross product surely predates Frobenius and Hurwitz.

Comment: @boywholived: I know, but I think it is a point worth mentioning; if not for you, then for others who may come across this question at some point in the future.

Comment: @Michael Albanese. Ok!. Thank you.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen. Sorry, I can't get your point. How can we know of something's utility even before we make useful theories based on definition ?.

Comment: I don't see how the fact that you can't put a field structure on $V_3$, say, could be a motivation for introducing a product operation on it. The cross and dot product in $\Bbb R^3$ are useful for classical geometry and physics, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why there aren't '3-dimensional numbers' (or higher) is deep and hard. Mathematicians looked for such things for a long time.

But so that you have a concrete reference, what you are interested in is the idea behind the proofs of [the Frobenius Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29), which says that the only multiplications that behave mostly like what we think of as multiplication are the reals and the complexes (and the quaternions, if we don't care for commutativity) or [Hurwitz's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28normed_division_algebras%29), which essentially says the same thing but with a different background.

One way to think of it, maybe, is to generalize the idea that multiplication of complex units lead to rotations on the unit circle. Similarly, multiplications of real units lead to degenerate rotations on the degenerate 1-dimensional unit circle. So you might think that higher dimensional multiplication of units would also have to do with rotations on a higher dimensional sphere. But as soon as you go past 2-dimensions, rotations don't commute. It is possible for $r_1 \circ r_2$ to be different than $r_2 \circ r_1$, where $r_i$ are rotations of a sphere. What this means is that we might not expect commutativity, to say the least.

It should also be pointed out that the 4-dimensional number system, the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), are naturally linked to spheres and rotations, and in fact do not have commutativity. I cannot think of another heuristic to explain why the octonions lose associativity, though.